# MySql Java Connectivity throws exception.(UPDATE)

Tags: java, mysql, connectivity

I've been trying to execute the following code in a java program for a while from a button. Tried everything but it still throws an exception.
I've already made the table and have put a single record in it.

```
    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
try{
     Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
     String UID="root";
     String PWD="123";
     String DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project";
     Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,UID,PWD);

     String CatalogID=jTextField3.getText();
     String Title=jTextField4.getText();
     String Author=jTextField5.getText();
     String Price=jTextField6.getText();
     String Category=jTextField7.getText();

     Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
     String q="UPDATE table1 SET title='"+Title+"' author='"+Author+"' category='"+Category+"' price="+Price+" WHERE id="+CatalogID+";";
     stmt.executeUpdate(q);
}

catch(Exception e){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error");
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgott the `,` between your columns:

```
String q="UPDATE table1 SET title='"+Title+"', author='"+Author+"', category='"+Category+"', price="+Price+" WHERE id="+CatalogID+";";
```

btw. its better to use `PreparedStatement`. You open a door for sql injection attacks.

Comment: Tried, Problem still persists'

Comment: which exception do you get exactly?